# Two Custom Post Types, Share Two Taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have two custom post types

- Hotels
- Things to do

And I have two taxonomies

- Activities
- Regions

So when a user sees a **Hotel** (custom post): the user can then see

- the region it's in
- what activities they can do.

*And viceversa as well*

When the user sees **Things To Do**, he can see in which **Region** it is and what **Hotels** have the same type of **Activity** nearby.

The problem if I use two custom post type and create a taxonomy for it, I have no way of discerning each taxonomy related to a custom post:

> Example: **Hotels** in X **Region**

I would get both the **Hotels** and **Things to do** custom post, within that taxonomy.

---

It's basically the same issue [as this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11697/a-shared-custom-taxonomy-between-two-custom-post-types) (which doesn't have any great answer).

Comment: so if I understand you correctly, you want two separate taxonomy term pages for each term, one for each post type?

Comment: Correct. Because if you think about it, there are hotels and attractions.

Both hotels and activities are in a region.

And both hotels and activities are suitable for a type of activity (say Romantic Hotels).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer set different taxonomies with distinct slug for them, I'm dealing with a project alike yours:

- Hotels (taxonomy is *continent-hotels*) values: Europe, Asia etc
- Places (taxonomy is *continent-places*) values: Europe, Asia etc

Even if both itens share same taxonomy and value, is easier to link the content than filter in frontend. Maybe I'm wrong but things seems tidier this way.

You can use non-hierarchical taxonomies for especific items such Hotels (romantic, economic, etc).

Comment: I went for this route in the end. I just figured it would be "cleaner" to go with one for each thing.

I just wish I didn't lose as much time, frozen, unknowing what to do. I am sure you can relate to those moments (where we seek an answer and freeze for days finding it) only to come up empty-handed

Comment: I see, we have thousand resources in WordPress but still anything is better than the paper and pen approach, sometimes a diagram too. We also have to think about who wll kepp the site and how, so things can't get too whimsical.